# Can't retrieve data from twitter

Tags: python, twitter, jupyter-notebook, tweepy

I'm trying to retrieve data from twitter API using tweepy and Twitter doesn't allow me to connect to their API. here's what it said:

> "*403 Forbidden
> 453 - You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: [https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve*"](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve*%22)

i've been applied to Elevated access from a week ago and still has no response. Any solution?

Comment: It is possible that reviewing Elevated access applications may take up to two weeks. source: https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/developer-account

Comment: This seems to be a question for twitter support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using tweepy to connect to the Twitter API, you can use the `tweepy.Client` object (instead of the `tweepy.API` object) to access Twitter API v2.

Comment: it worked, tysm